# Receiving a reviewer comments of the wrong paper from editor

Tags: peer-review

I have received a revesion in which one reviewer comments is related to my paper but the other reviewer comment is not related it is may be mistakenly copy other paper coments.
What can i do now?
Is there any reply template to editor.

Answer (score 8):

Don't overthink this. Write a concise and polite reply. Here is an example that is not perfect but should do it.

> Dear Professor ...,
>
> we recently received the reviews for our paper ...., which we
>   submitted to the journal ...., of which you are a/the editor of.
>
> While we found the comments by reviewer 1 very helpful, we noticed
>   that review number 2 was written for a different paper. We'd like to
>   hereby inform you of this likely administrative error. It is our
>   understanding that there is a second review for our paper, and hope
>   that its content will be equally helpful to improve our paper.
>
> Thanks,  Author name

If there is a submission number for your paper, include it as well (perhaps also submission date).

Comment: Up voted but I would do that by clearly attaching the response letter to ref 1. There is a high chance that the paper gets accepted on the basis of the only one report that OP has received, and of course took care of.

Comment: Also upvoted. I would only suggest doing it as quickly as possible. If email that is fast enough. If no email, then a phone call. It's delaying the other paper as well.